# Button click with productID always redirects to wrong page

Tags: javascript, url

I have a JavaScript function that redirects to different product pages based on the productID when a button is clicked. However, I'm encountering an issue where, regardless of which button I click (with productID of scse1 or bv9x), the page always redirects to the product page with the productID of tse2. URL parameters did work when it was used for one productID, but for unknown reason it's not working for multiple productIDs.

Here is my related Javascript and HTML code block :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const image1 = document.querySelector(".image1");
  const image2 = document.querySelector(".image2");
  const image3 = document.querySelector(".image3");
  const image4 = document.querySelector(".image4");
  const productBrand = document.querySelector(".productBrand");
  const productBrandModel = document.querySelector(".productBrandModel");
  const productPrice = document.querySelector(".productPrice");
  const productDescription = document.querySelector(".productDescription");
  const productHighlight1 = document.querySelector(".highlight1");
  const productHighlight2 = document.querySelector(".highlight2");
  const productHighlight3 = document.querySelector(".highlight3");
  
  const paramString = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  const productID = paramString.get("productID");

  if (productID === 'scse1') {
      image1.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/0erx2wjalz/1100px@1x/C21_C24251M_Scalpel_Crb_SE_1_ABB_D6.webp?color=E2ECF2&q=99";
      image2.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/qs23gi2pyn/1100px@1x/C21_C24251M_Scalpel_Crb_SE_1_ABB_D3.webp?color=E2ECF2&q=99";
      image3.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/ou3jhkydp5/1100px@1x/C21_C24251M_Scalpel_Crb_SE_1_ABB_PD.webp?color=E2ECF2&q=99";
      image4.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/ri0i4qyg0o/1100px@1x/C21_C24251M_Scalpel_Crb_SE_1_ABB_D1.webp?color=E2ECF2&q=99"
      productBrand.textContent = "cannondale";
      productBrandModel.textContent = "Scalpel Carbon SE 1";
      productPrice.textContent = "$4,700";
      productDescription.textContent = "Scalpel SE is the ultimate marathon racer and high-speed trail slayer. World Cup fast and all-mountain fierce – this is next-level cross-country mountain bike performance.";
      productHighlight1.textContent = "Lightweight carbon FlexPivot frame / New RockShox Sid Select+ RL 120mm fork / Integrated Cannondale App connectivity";
      productHighlight2.textContent = "Shimano XT hydraulic disc 12-speed group / HollowGram crank";
      productHighlight3.textContent = "HollowGram 25 S carbon tubeless-ready wheels / Cannondale DownLow dropper post / Stash kit";
      document.title = "Gear up | Scalpel Carbon SE1";
  } else if(productID === 'bv9x'){
      image1.src = '';//
      image2.src = '';// Leaving these 3 src empty, cuz I didn't find a proper img.
      image3.src = '';//
      image4.src = 'https://www.polygonbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/MY23-BEND-R9V-P.png'; // Update this with appropriate image source
      productBrand.textContent = "cannondale";
      productBrandModel.textContent = "Bend V9X";
      productPrice.textContent = "$4,000";
      productDescription.textContent = "A mountain bike built to raise your game and ignite a passion for the trail. Designed for the mountains and ready for anything.";
      productHighlight1.textContent = "Premium SmartForm C2 Alloy frame / RockShox 35 Silver R 120mm 120mm fork";
      productHighlight2.textContent = "SRAM SX Eagle 12-speed drivetrain / Shimano MT400 hydraulic disc brakes";
      productHighlight3.textContent = "Integrated connectivity with Cannondale App / dropper seatpost";
      document.title = "Gear up | Bend V9X";
  } else if(productID === 'tse2'){
      image1.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/tsmcgaee6k/1100px@1x/C21_C26201M_Trail_SE_2_EMR_D5.webp?color=e0f1ee&q=99";
      image2.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/2hbbm76enp/1100px@1x/C21_C26201M_Trail_SE_2_EMR_D3.webp?color=e0f1ee&q=99";
      image3.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/fr6dfv3kgd/1100px@1x/C21_C26201M_Trail_SE_2_EMR_PD.webp?color=e0f1ee&q=99";
      image4.src = "https://embed.widencdn.net/img/dorelrl/a1roymo8k1/1100px@1x/C21_C26201M_Trail_SE_2_EMR_D1.webp?color=e0f1ee&q=99";
      productBrand.textContent = "cannondale";
      productBrandModel.textContent = "Trail SE2";
      productPrice.textContent = "$2,010";
      productDescription.textContent = "A mountain bike built to raise your game and ignite a passion for the trail. Designed for the mountains and ready for anything.";
      productHighlight1.textContent = "Premium SmartForm C2 Alloy frame / RockShox 35 Silver R 120mm 120mm fork";
      productHighlight2.textContent = "SRAM SX Eagle 12-speed drivetrain / Shimano MT400 hydraulic disc brakes";
      productHighlight3.textContent = "Integrated connectivity with Cannondale App / dropper seatpost";
      document.title = "Gear up | Trail SE2";
  } 
});
```

```html
<div class="slides-container">
  <div class="slide active slide1">
    <h1 class="brand">Cannondale</h1>
    <h2 class="model">Scalpel Carbon <bold>SE 1</bold></h2>
    <img class="modelImg" src="assets/slider/Scalpel Carbon SE 1.png" />
    <button class="learn" id="scse1" onclick="location.href='productPages.html?productID=scse1'">Buy now</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide2" >
    <h1 class="brand">Polygon</h1>
    <h2 class="model">Bend <bold>v9x</bold></h2>
    <img
      class="modelImg"
      src="assets/slider/BendV9X.png"
      style="height: 700px; top: -10px"
    />
    <button class="learn" id="bv9x" onclick="location.href='productPages.html?productID=bv9x'">Buy now</button>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide3">
    <h1 class="brand">Cannondale</h1>
    <h2 class="model">Trail <bold>se 2</bold></h2>
    <img
      class="modelImg"
      src="assets/slider/trail se 2.png"
      style="height: 720px; top: -70px"
    />
    <button class="learn" id="tse2" onclick="location.href='productPages.html?productID=tse2'">Buy now</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've verified that the id attributes of the buttons correspond correctly to the respective productID. However, when clicking on any button, the page always redirects to the product page with the productID of tse2.

I would appreciate any insights into why this redirection issue is occurring and how to ensure that clicking each button redirects to the correct product page based on its productID. Thank you!

For example, when I click the button with the productID of scse1, it leads me to the page with the productID tse2 and the URL looks like this : **productPages.html?productID=tse2**.

Comment: Is this HTML inside of a <form> element? Since the buttons don't have a type on them, the default type is "submit", so it might be that you're seeing a submit event rather than your intended redirect?

Comment: Did you try a hard reload (ctrl-f5) ?  I wonder if an out-of-date page got cached.

Comment: It seems to work perfectly in the stack snippet. When you click the "scse1" button, the frame's src changes to `//stacksnippets.net/productPages.html?productID=scse1`

Comment: Answer to Jacob :

No it's not inside a form elem

Comment: Answer to James : I did, I will try it again tho...

Comment: Answer to Davi : That's weird...

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code through an AI tool and got the following suggestions:

1. Use window.location.href explicitly:
   Instead of relying on location.href, explicitly use window.location.href in
   your click event handlers.
2. Add return false;:
   In your onclick handlers, add return false; at the end. This prevents the
   default action of the anchor element, which might be conflicting with your
   redirection.
   Buy now

Comment: Could tell me the AI tool you used?

Comment: Github co-pilot.Was the solution helpful?

Comment: Where do I add return false? Inside the onclick?

Comment: I ran few tests, when I click the buttons they always log the ID tse2.

Comment: Do you have more suggestions?

Comment: not now, will make a block of time in the morning to reproduce your issue. Please send a link to your github repo if you can.

Comment: Here's the netlify app : https://radiant-caramel-93fe18.netlify.app/

There are few pages that are about to be completed... currently only the buttons in the carousel works.